# Word for letting something pass through unmodified

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to phrase the sentence "The system lets certain inputs pass through unmodified" more directly.

Could anyone suggest a word to replace the parenthesised 'phrase' below?

"The system (lets-pass-through-unmodified) certain inputs".

Comment: "The system *is transparent to* certain inputs".

Comment: Just ditch the ***lets*** component. *"The system passes certain inputs through unmodified"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a single word, but you *could* use "preserve the value", e.g.

"The system preserves the value of certain inputs."

However, I prefer your original sentence as it's unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, I like this suggestion. The sentence occurs in a list of sentences with a common format, so I am going to change it.

Comment: Depending on your audience, even "preserve" may be ambiguous - e.g., a system that takes data in one format but sends it in a different format, may "preserve" the data (i.e. the data stream represents the same information) while modifying it to support the different format (examples include converting from big-endian to little-endian, converting analog to digital, and converting text from one character set to another). "The system preserves the input" may mean that it doesn't do any format correction, or it may mean that it preserves the *information* while converting its format.

Comment: Good point. In my case the preservation of the format is already documented by the type system, so I'm comfortable leaving it at "preserves the value".

Answer (score 0):

The abbreviation o.k., whence comes the transitive verb “to okay,” stands for “ohne Korregierung” [German for “without correction”]. So, how about “to okay?”

Comment: OK is short for "oll korrekt". I've never once heard "ohne Korregierung". (In fact the word should be spelled *Korrigierung*, and then dropped and replaced with *Korrektur*.) But that is beside the point. The etymology of the word has nothing to do with whether or not it answers the question at hand, so I am not sure why you bring it up at all.